# Before/After hook without tag runs for tagged tests as well

Tags: tags, cucumber, hook

I have a feature that has prod tests to be run on prod server. Its tagged @prod. I have other non-tagged tests that can run in test envs.

In env.rb I have a Before do .. end that opens a new browser and sets up test to run in test env. I also have and a Before('@prod') block that sets up tests helpers to run in prod account.

When I run just the prod test, using cucumber --tags @prod, it runs prod tests. I expect only the Before('@prod') to run. However I see that both the BEfore blocks in env.rb file are run, creating 2 new browser instances and prod test running in second browser window. When my suite  of 7 scenarios are done I have 7 blank open browser windows which my test util setup from non-tagged Before.

Given any valid test merchant account  # features/step_definitions/ConsumerPortal.rb:1
      We are in plain Before
      We are in @prod Before
 When login to pos portal as 'pos' user

I see the same happening for After tag to logout and close browser as well. Tagged one is run first and then the plain After tag. If I can read what tag a test has in my env.rb Before, I can setup accordingly. Is tehre a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use negation tags with your before tags.

```
@Before("~@prod")
@After("~@prod")
```

This will prevent the Before and After tags from running for all @prod tags.

Or else in general, all @Before and @After methods run for any tags.